How to prove If the method assigns the parameter to refer to a different object in passing a value type by reference?
As per https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/method-parameters#params-modifier
When you pass a value type by reference:
A) If the method assigns the parameter to refer to a different object, those changes aren't visible from the caller.
public int Sq(ref int number)
        {
            // Assigned a different instance means it address is different from what is passed  
            number = new int();
            number = 10;
            return number;
        }

But here changes are visible in called
B) If the method modifies the state of the object referred to by the parameter, those changes are visible from the caller.
public int Sq(ref int number)
        {     
            //Modifying number to 10 and this cannot be visible in called method 
            number = 10;
            return number;
        }

I understood B but how to prove A? Please help me to provide the correct code to prove A.

Does this answer your question? value type passed by reference in C#

Also check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5746873/where-and-why-use-int-a-new-int on what number = new int(); actually does (and not does).

number=new int() and number=10 are two separate assignments of a new value to 'number', you are not "filling in" the "object" assigned in the first one (for one thing, int is a struct), but just overwriting it

This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65418824/object-passing-reference-vs-value/65419301#65419301 and this too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52619015/why-some-c-sharp-library-functions-dont-follow-the-ref-parameter-passing-conv/52619251#52619251

This is absolutely not true - Because any placement in a variable is anyway a type of reassignment.
You can run the following examples and see:
Example of objects:
public static string Sq(ref string str)
        {
            str = new string("blabla");
            return str;
        }
        public static string Sq2(ref string str)
        {
            str = "blabla";
            return str;
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string sq="hi", sq2="hi";
            Console.WriteLine("sq="+sq+"  sq2="+sq2);//output: sq=hi  sq2=hi
            Sq(ref sq);
            Sq2(ref sq2);
            Console.WriteLine("sq="+ sq+ "  sq2="+ sq2);//output: sq=blabla  sq2=blabla
        }

Example of variables by value:
 public static int Sq(ref int number)
        {
            number = new int();
            number = 10;
            return number;
        }
        public static int Sq2(ref int number)
        {
            number = 10;
            return number;
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello, World!");
            int sq=5, sq2=5;
            Console.WriteLine("sq="+sq+"  sq2="+sq2);//output:sq=5  sq2=5
            Sq(ref sq);
            Sq2(ref sq2);
            Console.WriteLine("sq="+ sq +"  sq2="+ sq2);//output:sq=10  sq2=10

        }

The variable sq has changed even though it has been assigned a new place in the function. (This examples is runnable)
